# Cosmos DB use alias in Order By clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Cosmos DB (may apply to others) I want to create a query with an alias (AS keyword) in the select part.

```
SELECT c['value'].id AS Abc 
FROM c 
ORDER BY Abc
```

In the ORDER BY part I want to use the alias. How do I do that? The above SQL doesn't do it.

Comment: Not familiar with Cosmos, but in some DBMS you cannot order by an alias name. You could wrap it as one alternative... `select * from (select col1 as abc from c) order by abc`

Comment: @Isolated every derived table still needs an alias

Comment: `...c)z order by abc`.

Comment: @nbk Depends on DBMS, but certainly doesn't hurt to add it even if not required. Again, not sure on Cosmos, so maybe that one requires an alias.

Comment: Or you can order by the ordinal, at least in most DBMS.

Comment: @Andrew Not in CosmosDB https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNYQ7.png

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/order-by) does mention

> A sort column can be specified as a name *or property alias*

So you might expect the usage of the column alias defined by `AS` to just work. But it didn't for me either (in the emulator).

As @Isolated states the following works

```
SELECT   x.Abc
FROM     ( SELECT c['value'].id AS Abc
           FROM    c ) x
ORDER BY x.Abc
```

The derived table needs an alias for this (I used `x` in this example) and this needs to be used in the `ORDER BY`.

Trying just `ORDER BY Abc`

gives

> Identifier 'Abc' could not be resolved.